# Calculate up to two decimal places in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, integer

I want to **Calculate up to two decimal places** in my Calculations but I can't

For example:

```
a = 93
b = 1
c = float(93/1)
print c
```

I want to `print` like this :

```
93.00
```

But it print like this :

```
93.0
```

Is there any function to do this or is there any way to do this?

Comment: no there is float

Comment: It is a float because it has a decimal part (even if that decimal part is equal to 0). If it were an integer, you would simply have `93`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an explicit format to that float

```
print("%.2f" % round(c,2))
```

test it on a jupyter

https://try.jupyter.org/

---

[image]

Comment: thanks for accepting the answ... I alredy upvoted the question too :)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change your code to

```
c = float(93.0/1.0)
```

This is  because you are using integer division.

```
#  eg. 93/2 == 46
#  but 93.0/2 == 46.5 and
#      93.0/2.0 == 46.5
print c
```

then to print 2 decimal places you have to use python formatting

```
print "%.2f" % c
# 93.00
```